# MariaDB nested select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I have this table in MariaDB:

```
+-----------------+------+----------------+------------+------------------+------+--------+
| date            | host | process        | text       | num1             | num2 | suffix |
+-----------------+------+----------------+------------+------------------+------+--------+
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656876839 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656873333 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[4268] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
+-----------------+------+----------------+------------+------------------+------+--------+
```

From the table I need to find which num1 id has both suffix mt and dn.

So far I have one SELECT which can find me all num1's which have suffix 'mt' suffix.

```
SELECT num1
from table4
WHERE suffix = 'mt' group by num1;

+------------------+
| num1             |
+------------------+
| 1563866656871111 |
| 1563866656872222 |
| 1563866656873333 |
| 1563866656876839 |
+------------------+
```

From SELECT before I want to SELECT num1 which has suffix 'dn' too.

I tried this but it didn't work :(

```
SELECT num1 
FROM (SELECT num1 from table4 WHERE suffix = 'mt' group by num1)
WHERE num1=ID AND suffix = 'dn';
```

Comment: Why are you so determined to use a nested select?

Comment: I don't know. It just seemed to me easier way but apparently it isn't,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT num1
from table4
WHERE suffix IN ('mt', 'dn')
GROUP BY num1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT suffix) = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you it works.

Although I wonder if there is any solution with nested select and alias.

For example

```SELECT num1 
FROM (SELECT num1 from table4 WHERE suffix = 'mt' group by num1) as ident
WHERE num1=ident AND suffix = 'dn';```

Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @vladpoverin . . . There are alternative solutions.  However, you have duplicates so you need `GROUP BY` or `SELECT DISTINCT` anyway.  Hence, you might as well just using the aggregation solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My next problem is to ignore suffix 'dn' which has different time for 74 hours.

So find num1 which suffix 'dn' is arrived later than 72 hours or don't find the num1 if its dn didn't arrived until 72 hours...

Do you have any ideas how to manage it?

Comment: @vladpoverin . . . Ask a *new* question, with sample data and desired results.